error : "Could not initalize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader"
So I'm creating simple Java program to read .xlsx file.
Here the code :
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
private String TestWorkbook(File[] excelFiles) {
String returnString = null;
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (File file : excelFiles) {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
      
            if (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                rowIterator.next();
            }
           
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
                if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
                    numbers .add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }
            }

            for (String number: numbers ) {
                System.out.println("number= " + number);

            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return returnString = "OK";
}

From code above the lib that I have load are:
poi 5.2.5
poi-ooxml 5.2.5
poi-ooxml-lite 5.2.5
but somehow getting above error , error : "Could not initalize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader"
what is wrong with my code or I missing something?

The error message “Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader” indicates that there was an issue initializing the POIXMLTypeLoader class from the Apache POI library. Let’s explore some possible solutions:
Try to check Dependencies. Check that you have the correct version of the Apache POI library (including the necessary dependencies) in your project.
Make sure that the required JAR files (such as poi-ooxml.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas.jar, and others) are included in your classpath.

How I can find the dependency of these jars? I have include mentioned jars above to my classpath. but somehow still same error I got. I'm still curious what dependency on this  POIXMLTypeLoader class, is it due to log4j or something. Because I tried in POM.. and import only org.apache.poi.ooxml without log4j it's working.
But when I was include log4 into pom. Above error will appear.
